# How to host/publish a webpage built in Meteorjs

Tags: meteor, github

I built a web application using MeteorJS and pushed to GitHub. Now I want to publish/deploy it on GitHub as well, so colleagues and lecturer will be able to view the page and its files on GitHub.

I know I can deploy it on meteor.com, but was wondering if it's possible to deploy it on GitHub.

Could anyone list all the steps in details how to do it? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't, you can only put up static content on GitHub.  See: [How to publish a website made by Node.js to Github Pages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages)

Answer (score -1):

To make your app viewable, deploy it from the app's directory using "meteor deploy <your app name>"

Note that the deployed name (what ends up at the start of the URL (after the possibly invisible "http://" of course)) does not have to match the project name. e.g., your project name could be "meatier" but then you can use "meteor deploy platypus"

In the latter case, after it has been processed and uploaded, it will be available to anyone at platypus.meteor.com