# Include node_modules/ folder to push to gh-pages branch

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, github

I'm trying to push a site to the gh-pages branch on Github... I need to include the **node_modules/ folder** but git is not even letting me add it to commit the changes... I understand this is the desired behavior, since you don't want to include the dependencies while developing. But I'm trying to deploy live here... so I need to include all the dependencies...

Any ideas?

Comment: You should be able to commit the changes if `node_modules/` is not in your `.gitignore`

Comment: is not in my `.gitignore` file... but still... is not adding the folder :/

Comment: Can you link to your project if its public?

Comment: sure! is here https://github.com/leojavier/argonite-site/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Checked it out. After `npm install` I was able to commit the folder. However, Github pages only hosts static sites, so you do not need to check in `node_modules`. See this stackoverflow issue for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15719098/3108699

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way but I was able to get it to work by moving the node_modules folder to extra_modules and then updating my script references in index.html.

As long as the modules don't include any executable files, it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add `!node_modules/` to your .gitignore file