# Is it possible to host interactive R Markdown files on Github Pages?

Tags: r, github, shiny, r-markdown, github-pages

As the title says, I would like to create posts on Github Pages that are interactive R Markdown files (meaning that it has Shiny apps embedded in it). Is this possible to do in Github Pages? If so, how can I do it; and if not, what's the best (free) way to host interactive RMD/Shiny pages?

Comment: RStudio offers [shinyapps.io](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shinyapps/)

Comment: @Gregor I am aware, just wondering if there's a way to create blog-like posts with embedded shiny instead of having to link to separate shinyapps.io pages.

Comment: I believe that no server side tech is allowed on github pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages As such I can't see how you could do this other than link to some other host.

Comment: You can run RMarkdown files with html widgets embedded ( highcharter,leaflet etc.) on github, but not full blown shiny apps. Shiny apps can only be run on a server with RStudio Server installed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While it's not possible to host fully-fledged Shiny apps on Github pages (Indeed, as @Gregor suggested, shinyapps.io is useful for this), the devs for Shiny have been working to make some of the functionality run completely on the client-side via [htmlwidgets](http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_leaflet.html).

Here is a simple example running on Github pages:

**README.Rmd**

````
## Example of displaying htmlwidgets on a Github pages site

```{r}
# Source: http://www.htmlwidgets.org/showcase_plotly.html
library(plotly)
p <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = clarity)) +
            geom_bar(position = "dodge")
ggplotly(p)
```
````

**Rendered HTML**

[image: Screenshot of htmlwidgets demo]

(Live version: [Github pages htmlwidget demo](https://khughitt.github.io/shiny-htmlwidget-example/README.html))

For more complex interactions, including communicating between widgets entirely on the client-side, check out [Joe Cheng's recent crosstalk demo](https://github.com/jcheng5/crosstalk-demo) from UserR! 2016.

Comment: how do you translate an rmarkdown knitr interactive shiny doc into a working github pages webpage? Do I simply change my rmd file to an html file??

Answer (score 2):

### In 2023, you can host Shiny apps on Github pages using the `shinylive` package

From the [documentation page](https://shiny.posit.co/py/docs/shinylive.html) on Posit's website:

> The traditional way of deploying Shiny involves in a separate server and client: the server runs Python and Shiny, and clients connect via the web browser. Each client keeps an open websocket connection as long as they are using the application.

But

> When an application is deployed with Shinylive, Python and Shiny run in the web browser: the browser is effectively both the client and server for the application. There is a web server that serves files, but it does not run Python or Shiny—it can be a “dumb” static web server.

This means that you can host a Shiny app via GitHub pages.

#### A high-level workflow example

All stolen from RamiKrispin's excellent [example repository](https://github.com/RamiKrispin/shinylive)

As shinylive apps are serverless, you can deploy your app into [Github Pages](https://pages.github.com/). First, create your app with the following step:

```bash
shiny create myapp
```

This will create the app file - `app.py` with the default shinylive example under the `myapp` folder:

```bash
.
└── myapp
    └── app.py
```

Next, update your app and build the site with the `shiny static` command:

```
shiny static myapp docs
```

We mapped the app folder - `myapp` to the website folder `docs` (Github Pages required the website name to set as `docs`). This will add the following folders:

```bash
.
├── docs
│   ├── edit
│   └── shinylive
│       ├── jquery.terminal
│       │   ├── bin
│       │   ├── css
│       │   └── js
│       ├── pyodide
│       │   └── fonts
│       ├── pyright
│       └── shiny_static
│           └── edit
└── myapp
```

You can test locally your app with the following command:

```bash
python3 -m http.server --directory docs 8008
```

and open on your browser using `http://localhost:8008/`.

**Note:** Any time you change your app, you will have to run `shiny static myapp docs` to update the `docs` folder.

Once you finilize your app, commit and push your changes and open your repo on Github and go to the `Settings` tab and select the `Pages` option (blue boxes):

Next, select under `Build and deployment` select the `Deploy from branch` option (green box) and under the branch option your branch you want to deploy from and the `docs` folder (purple box).

The site should be ready few minutes after with the following URL:

```
YOUR_GITHUB_USER_PROFILE.github.io/YOUR_REPO_NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

When you render an rmd file you can also knit it to HTML as well and you can then host that page on github pages.

Comment: How do you knit it to HTML?