# Is it possible to have tabpanel in Markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

I'd like to know if there is a way to have tabs (tabpanels) on Github in Markdown in the `README.md`.

My goal is to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you considered Github Pages for this? Seems like a bit more than a README should handle.

Comment: Yeah, but that is a longer term project, I wished something quicker..

Comment: Related: [Add tabbed code snippets in markdown](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/17381).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes is possible using shinytabs   in rmarkdown

see this page

http://scottshepard.io/markdown-pages-as-tabs-in-shiny/

rmarkdown is the most advance version of markdown that i saw

in github flavored  markdown its impossible  Except that you make a fork using jquery or bootstrap

I do not think it's possible in gfm I've seen it for markdown forks and only R It has those features

you can use ajax maybe

https://rstudio.github.io/shinydashboard/structure.html

you should see this post [Is it possible to host interactive R Markdown files on Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138307/is-it-possible-to-host-interactive-r-markdown-files-on-github-pages)

also

Comment: Pity that is not feasible in gfm, however thanks for your answer, really useful tips!

Comment: Link is broken: http://scottshepard.io/markdown-pages-as-tabs-in-shiny/