# Not able to deploy my web app on github.io

Tags: node.js, github, github-pages

I recently made my github.io repository to deploy my completed app that I was previously running on my personal computer. Here is the structure of my app -

```
bin
public
server
app.js
package.json
```

The page wants to read index.html file but I want it to first read app.js and then the flow is automated from app.js.

How can i make github.io read my app.js file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your content is in fact a static site (only HTML CSS and client side JavaScript), then you might want to upload the content of your public folder.

Otherwise, sorry, but you can't run Node (or any other server side tech) on GitHub pages. Have a look at Heroku, AWS, Google Cloud, and so on ...