# How to call an API in GitHub

Tags: java, spring-boot, github

I have Uploaded a simple REST API java project in github. How can I call the API via `url` in GitHub to see if the API is working? I have read some documents about `curl`, but I am not sure how to use it.

```
 https://api.github.com/repos/github_user_name/project_name/getUser?id=100
```

Comment: I don't think the GitHub API works that way. By using the GitHub API, you're not interacting with your own code. Your code isn't actually running. The API exists for getting data such as your GitHub username, project name, etc... none of your code is running.

Comment: I have addressed your question "Can we use Gitlab for achieving the result ?" in my edited answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be able to cal your own API using a GitHub URL.

You cannot execute any custom process on the server (GitHub) side, except [GitHub actions](https://github.com/features/actions) (like [those ones](https://github.com/sdras/awesome-actions)).

You can [use for instance Netlify to test your API from your GitHub project](https://blog.antoine-augusti.fr/2019/01/serving-a-json-rest-api-without-infrastructure-thanks-to-netlify/).

---

> Can we use Gitlab for achieving the result ?

No: GitHub or GitLab are for hosting repositories, not for serving any custom services from those repositories (beside [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) or [GitLab Pages](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/), for publishing static websites directly from a repository)

Again, for exposing a REST API, you need a third party server.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub only serves static web pages and does not provide any way to host a server. Your Spring Boot app is essentially a server so it is not possible to check the API through GitHub as you are intending. There are some free solutions out there like [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) which you can use for testing purposes.

Related: [How to publish a website made by Node.js to Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages)

Comment: Can we use `Gitlab` for achieving the result ?

Comment: Nope, both Github and Gitlab creates web pages and not web servers which is what you need to host an API.