# Create a list of links to all pages in a directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to web development (more of a data science background with R), but I feel like this has to be possible and pretty simple, but I'm stumped.  On my main index page, I want to include a list of all files included in my `pages` directory as links.  I want this so I don't have to set up the links manually every time -- instead, links will be created for a page when it is saved in the `pages` directory.

My first thought was that there had to be a way to read the files in the directory, and from there I could build my list of links.  It seems that JS can't access the server side to read the directory, though (if I'm understanding this correctly).

On [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274329/get-list-of-filenames-in-folder-with-javascript) answer they suggest using Node.js with the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync('/pages/');
```

I tried dropping that in my index page as I would javascript code, but that didn't work. If this is the solution I should pursue, where do I put the node.js code in my website directory?  If it matters, I have the site hosted on GitHub.

I'd appreciate any guidance on this -- and I fully accept that I might be going about this in completely the wrong manner.

Comment: Github does not really run node.js stuff. You need a heroku deployment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages

Comment: If that list of pages only updates occasionally you could store it in json file that you manually update and use ajax/fetch() to read that file