# Deploying react to github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm

Im trying to deploy my react application to github pages from node.js.
But when i run  `npm run deploy`  I get this error

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! markdown-previewer@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the markdown-previewer@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\sherw\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-29T14_46_53_628Z-debug.log
```

I followed some tutorials to do this, but almost all of them had the same steps which i followed correctly.

Am i missing something here? Or is it some problem with npm?

Comment: GitHub pages host only static HTML pages. See [How to publish a website made by Node.js to Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages). Maybe you can use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) to create a bundle.

Comment: Did you build the app before deploying?

Comment: No i haven't built the app yet, but there was already a pre-built demo app in the source directory

Comment: @SherwinFernandes show us some examples please :)