# How to render dynamic pages on GitHub Pages?

Tags: node.js, github, github-pages

I just wanted to make a chatbot REST API on GitHub Pages, but I can't get it to render a dynamic page made with Express and Node.js. I just want to know if we can somehow render dynamic pages on GitHub Pages.

Comment: You can't, GHP only serves static content.

Comment: So can I do that on firebase hosting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to publish a website made by Node.js to Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github pages is only used to serve static content and does not support any server-side scripting.
Firebase hosting is also for static content hosting and also does not support server-side scripting.
You should use firebase cloud functions for any of your back-end services/scripting.

Some resources to host server-side services : https://free-for.dev/#/?id=paas