# GitHub pages only showing ReadMe file

Tags: github-pages

I'm trying to host my webpages into GitHub pages but it seems to only show my Readme file.

GitHub repo: https://github.com/tomertal3/asafwle

Website:

https://tomertal3.github.io/asafwle/

Comment: You need to build your app

Comment: also see [How to publish a website made by Node.js to Github Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719098/12101554)

Comment: i built it, it worked but when i tried to make changes and push them, it switched to showing only the readme file

Comment: remove `/build` from `.gitignore`, then add the build folder to git, the push again, then go into your repo's setting on github and change the root folder to `/build`

Comment: @Samathingamajig where do i change the root folder, did you mean inside "Build and deployment"? because i can only see /root and /docs in there

Comment: you may need to rename the folder. alternatively you can put `build` on it's own branch

Answer (score 1):

As long as your [publishing source](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#publishing-from-a-branch) is the `gh-pages` branch, folder "root", your GItHub Pages website should reflect your gh-pages branches.

Add to that branch a [`.nojekyll` file](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/), your site should be published as is.