# Is there a way to deploy a node.js web app to GitHub pages using GitHub actions?

Tags: node.js, github-actions, github-pages

I have a web app that uses node.js and I want to deploy it to GitHub pages. I know that I will need to use actions, but I have no idea how to go about doing it. I know this was asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages), but it doesn't have the most recent answers. Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: The other answer is still up to date. You still can't do it. Github actions won't allow your code to run indefinitely

Comment: GitHub Pages is a static hosting service. You can't run server-side code.

Comment: @tadman What if I don't have any server-side code, would it be possible then?

Comment: Yes, but then that's not a Node app. It's a client-side app. You can use Node during the build process, though, if you use a container-based build. It's just that the Node process there wraps up long before any requests are served.