# Godaddy not rendering my angular project (with Git Hub Pages)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, github-pages, godaddy-api

I just deploy my project with Git Hub Pages and also add my custom domain from godaddy. The deploy worked correctly but godaddy is not rendering my site, even though github pages render it correctly. The html is like this right now:
`

`

In app.module.ts the code is :
`const appRoutes:Routes=[ {path:'', component: LoginComponent}, {path:'disk', component: DiskComponent} ]`

I tried to change the CNAME a lot of times but it doesn't work.

Comment: GitHub Pages only supports static web content as far as I'm aware. https://stackoverflow.com/a/15719098/9153845

Answer (score 0):

a bit late here, but I have managed to get my angular site working on github and GoDaddy and the execution is slightly different.

Assuming you are deploying to root the main steps to take are:

1. Make a build: `ng build --configuration production`
2. Zip build and upload build to public_html folder in cpanel
3. Extract contents (delete old contents if there, cpanel extracting DOES NOT overwrite old content last time I checked).
4. Add .htaccess file - SUPER IMPORTANT - If you do not do this your site breaks on refresh and routes won't work properly!

Here is a generic .htaccess file that should work for all basic sites:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  
  # Redirection of requests to index.html
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
  
  # Redirect all non-file routes to index.html
  RewriteRule ^(?!.*\.).*$ index.html [NC,L]
  
  #Force HTTPS (I believe there is a better way than this, I may edit later)
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

A few other things...

- If you decide to have your app not in the root (public_html) you'll have to change your base href in your build and htaccess paths accordingly...
- I routed slightly differently (I did it in app-routing.module.ts) but if it works on GitHub it should work on GoDaddy. I also didn't have to change the CName for my site.
- GoDaddy can be a major pain with updating changes across its servers for angular builds in general since it's a lot slower than GitHub pages, so it can take some time to see changes reflected across all paths... don't forget to delete cache as well when checking for updates because it will show you your old site from the cache sometimes even after it's actually updated...

Hope this helps people and good luck!