# Deploying Node.js app in Github.io without third party packages

Tags: node.js, express, package, package.json, deploying

Recently I have done my first Express app in Node.js. I want to share my project with potential employers, clients or more likely to happen with friends.

But I want to make a home page, which will contain my multiple projects in node.js, as I am planning to continue with React.js. I have made some research on this topic, but left unsure of my idea. Can you please give your best advice.

I want to make structure of my website like this.

```
/
 /bin
 /controllers
 /models
 /public
 /routes
 /views
   /myFirstProject
     /bin
     /models
     /routes ...etc
   
   /mySecondProject
     /bin
     /... etc
 app.js
```

Also, here I found that I can use [Harp.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27481279/11056331) according to that respected comment, but I found that its website in not Https, and may be files can be damaged. I may not understand to analyze the code inside its packages.

Do you know any other direct methods to deploy a Node.js in someuser.Github.io? Thank you very much for your support and interest.

I tried to make research on this topic. Result is that only using other JS modules, I can somehow deploy the project, I didn't try myself, as I am afraid to include unreliable source of code in my project.

Also I understood that Harp.js compiles code, which I think can slow down opening the page.

Comment: You have to deploy the project to a hosting that supports nodejs

Comment: As best I know, github.io does not support running your own nodejs backend.