Integration of GitPage and NodeJs APIs ( runs in ec2)
my node js apis whch is running on ec2 instance r nt wrkng in the githubpages (i usd apis in reactap  wrking in local but after deploinng in git page)
How to use my node js apis which run on aws ec2 instance in git hub pages( i enbables  acess for all 0/0.0.0)

i think this question seems to be similar to :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718649/how-to-publish-a-website-made-by-node-js-to-github-pages?noredirect=1&lq=1
please search for answers before posting quesitons

Please, rewrite you text in current English
